# Simulator suddenly could not connect to development server when run react-native project

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I use mac, I have never got this error before but today.
I tried to init a new project with "react-native init sampleProject" but nothing changed, both android and ios simulator has the same error.

Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Anyone has this problem?

Comment: Does your server really uses port 8081? Validate this!

Comment: run command to check  **lsof -i :8081** and then kill  same port  running
**adb kill-server -port** . Finally Restart your server again 

**react-native start**

Comment: Syed's comment should solve it, if you did not properly terminate your works before, this may happen when you try to run another project.

Comment: Hi guys, everything work fine when I uninstall watchman, I don't know what's wrong with watchman but finaly the problem was solved.

thank all.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your import in that file and make sure that you have run your project again after importing and installing any library.
Start new  terminal  and after that run your project .
If its not working then reverse your port using command

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Hope it will helps you.!